# How do I reduce the table width and the text overlapping of a very wide table in mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a very wide table in my html:

```
<section>
  <h1>My table</h1>
  <div class="tbl-header">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Change</th>
          <th>Change %</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

And this is my css:

```
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


/* demo styles */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}
```

When I view the table in screens with width <=1000 px, the table looks very clumsy and moreover the data in each cell overlaps the data in the adjacent cell, which just destroys the beauty of the table.

To fix this issue, I tried to give it a fixed width and make it scrollable:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  *{
    font-size: small;
  }
  section{
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  table{
     width: 60%;
     overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

But it was all in vain. How do I make the table fit the screen width (especially mobile devices)?

Answer (score 0):

Think this works,

```
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

And make sure that you don't have `white-space: nowrap` in these tds. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_word-break) is more about word break

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on how you want your table to look on mobile devices. I would suggest making it responsive using media queries and using separate classes for mobile devices. You will have to adjust mostly heights, widths, and margins.
Here is an example that might help you:

```
<section class={'mobile-view-class'}>
```

in your css file:

```
    @media screen(max-width: 63.9375em){
    .mobile-view-class{
     table{
      width:fix-content;
      overflow: scroll;
     }
   .tbl-content{
     height: auto;
     overflow-x:scroll;
   }
   th{
    padding: 5px 5px;
   }
  tr {
   max-width:120px;
   white-space:pre-line
  }
  td{ 
   padding: 5px;
   max-height: 80px;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
 }
}
```